# Reference to undefined setting error with custom task in SBT?

Tags: sbt

I'm creating a task in SBT that will create a properly-formatted classpath, but I get an undefined setting error when I try to `compile`. The error is not useful enough to tell me what setting is undefined:

```
[error] Reference to undefined setting: 
[error] 
[error]   *:fullClasspath from *:fcp
[error]
```

This is for the following build configuration:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object TestBuild extends Build {
    override lazy val settings = super.settings ++ Seq(
        name := "blah", scalaVersion := "2.10.2"
    )

    lazy val fcp = TaskKey[String]("fcp", "create formatted classpath")
    lazy val fcpTask = fcp <<= fullClasspath map { tasks =>
        val cp = tasks.map(_.data.getName + ":")
        s"[Classpath]$cp[/Classpath]"
    }

    lazy val project = Project(
        "project", file("."), settings = settings ++ Seq(fcpTask)
    )
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Three things:

1)  You're removing all the default settings. When you create a project, you can specify a complete list of settings for the project (like you're currently doing) *or* you can *add* your settings configurations to the defaults.  If you change your project definition to the following, it should start working:

```
lazy val project = (
  Project("project", file("."))
  .settings(fcpTask)
)
```

2) You're placing settings into the `Build` itself.   If these settings don't exist on the `Project` level, then it will look into the `Build` for the settings.  However, things like `name` should probable be defined in the project.  So your complete build file would look like:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object TestBuild extends Build {
    lazy val fcp = TaskKey[String]("fcp", "create formatted classpath")
    lazy val fcpTask = fcp <<= fullClasspath map { tasks =>
        val cp = tasks.map(_.data.getName + ":")
        s"[Classpath]$cp[/Classpath]"
    }
    lazy val project = (
      Project("project", file("."))
      .settings(name := "blah", scalaVersion := "2.10.2")
      .settings(fcpTask)
    )
}
```

3)  You should select which *configuration* you want to pull your class path from.  Options:

- Runtime:  Includes the project's compiled classes + resource directories and dependencies
- Compile:  Include justs the dependencies used to compile the project
- Test:     Include all the dependencies used when testing (including the proejct itself)

What you had before is equivalent to `fullClasspath in Compile` IIRC.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Given that the "fcp <<= fullClasspath map { ...}" syntax is deprecated, what's the proper way to do this now?

Comment: Simply use the `:=` operator and directlyr reference the task or the setting key. Can you this?

`fcp := {
  val cp = fullClasspath.map(_.data.getName + ":");
  s"[Classpath]$cp[/Classpath]"
}`